# Building LLVM with CMake and Visual Studio

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am trying to build LLVM on Windows 8.1 with CMake, using Visual Studio 2013. I have done this before on other machines with no problems, and don't understand what the issue is here. Any help would be appreciated.

After running CMake, I get the following error:

```
Constructing LLVMBuild project information 
CMake Error at C:/.../llvm-3.5.0.cmake/LLVMBuild.cmake:8 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file Call Stack (most recent call first):     
CMakeLists.txt:383 (include)
```

I looked through the generated CMakeError and CMakeOutput files, and didn't find anything helpful (to me, anyway). Here's the first relevant-looking information from the CMakeError file:

```
  CheckIncludeFile.cxx

C:\...\llvm-3.5.0.cmake\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.cxx(1): 
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cxxabi.h': No such file or directory
[C:\...\llvm-3.5.0.cmake\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3681830091.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "C:\...\llvm-3.5.0.cmake\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3681830091.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.
```

I can provide the full file and/or any other needed information upon request.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am facing the same type of error, no matter which version I am building (tried everything from 3.2 to 3.6)

Comment: No, I never figured out how to fix the issue. Eventually, I installed [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), and then followed the instructions for downloading and compiling LLVM [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-with-llvm). This worked perfectly, but you can't use Visual Studio when doing it this way.

Comment: Also, note that you may have to play around with different options with the cygwin compilers before it will complete successfully. I believe I had to run the configure script with "CC=gcc CXX=G++ bindings=none".

Comment: I believe this is caused by interferance of software that is installed. I have an old Version (3.2) which used to build correctly. Now even this old Version does not build anymore. I will update here once I resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The missing `cxxabi.h` error normally occurs when you e.g. try to compile with `gcc` instead of `g++`.